# No me aparece la vista de relaciones de las tablas en phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

alguien me puede ayudar con esto:

[image: Imagen de phpMyAdmin]

No me parece la vista de relaciones, ya le agregué las llaves foráneas pero no me muestra esa vista. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: [checa esto](http://blogfbd.blogspot.com/2012/09/configurar-phpmyadmin-y-habilitar-el.html)

Comment: Gracias Luis Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Click en "Más"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Vista diseñador

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que sea esto lo que buscabas

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias :)